# Is this COM object subject to garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, com, garbage-collection, com-interop

I'm using a COM object from .NET using interop. The object basically fetch data from socket and fire some events for .NET layer to process. However, after a while, the COM object stops firing events which revealed later to be because it's collected by GC.

The structure of source code is similar to this one below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyEventGen gen = new MyEventGen();
    WeakReference wr = new WeakReference(gen);
    gen.ReceiveDataArray += 
            new _IMyEventGenEvents_ReceiveDataArrayEventHandler(gen_ReceiveDataArray);
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(wr.IsAlive);
    }
}

static void gen_ReceiveDataArray(ref Array indices, ref Array values)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

[image]

What I know so far:

- From what I understand, **object `gen` shouldn't be garbage-collected in any way.** Since the object is still active in the `Main` scope. But the result so far shows that the object was collected by GC.
- The object is only garbage-collected when built as **Release and run without debugging**. Running the Debug builds / running both modes under debugger are fine.
- The program will print the first "False" precisely after the **first Gen #0 Collection**.
- By accessing the object in the `while` loop, e.g. `Console.WriteLine(gen.ToString())` , prevent it from being GC'd!
- By adding another static field of `Program` class to keep its reference also prevent it from GC'd.
- Trying with different load of data, I found that GC only collects the object when Private Bytes reach over the threshold of ~ 3X MBs.
- Checking with [CLRProfiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx), mentioned object was GC'd as suspected.

Have I missed some important .NET GC's concepts? Is it possible to obtain the reason for object being GC'd? Is this, possibly, a known GC bug?

I'm using VS 2008 + .NET 3.5 SP1. Appreciate your thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use a COM object to reproduce this. Consider the following:

```
public class MyEventGen
{
    public event Action ReceiveDataArray;
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var gen = new MyEventGen();
        var wr = new WeakReference(gen);
        // this is the last time we access the 
        // gen instance in this scope so after this line it
        // is eligible for garbage collection
        gen.ReceiveDataArray += new Action(gen_ReceiveDataArray);

        // run the collector
        GC.Collect();
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(wr.IsAlive);
        }
    }

    static void gen_ReceiveDataArray()
    {
    }
}
```

Run it in Release mode and it will exhibit the same behavior. The `gen` object falls out of scope and is garbage collected because there is nothing to keep it alive during the execution of the loop.

Comment: Thanks Darin! Looks like I misunderstand the GC process all these years :')

Comment: @m3rLinEz, the thing is that in Release mode many optimizations are performed and the GC could become really aggressive. It is capable to understand that the `gen` variable is no longer used after the last access and it is collected. Keeping gen as a static variable should prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `gen` nor `wr` remain active in the Main scope during the execution of your `while` loop.
You enclosed the first three lines in braces which puts those variables in a child scope that is exited before your `while` loop begins.

Comment: I think this is not the case. I think the braces are a typo, otherwise his program wouldn't compile as he wouldn't be able to access the `wr` variable in the while loop and be able to print False.

Comment: Even the scope isn't enough to keep the objects alive: it's where the objects are used that counts (although the VS debugger keeps objects alive until the end of their scope). You can get surprises in Release builds where objects are collected in the middle of a method, or even part-way through a line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Your COM objects are eligible for destruction as soon as their .NET equivalents disappear from the program. The last time `gen` is used is when the `ReceiveDataArray += ...` call is made.

You should add a call to `GC.KeepAlive(gen)` at the point in the program where it's acceptable for cleanup to take place. Alternatively, if it needs to stay alive until the program exits, you could add it as a `static` field.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Just to confirm, so I can't know if an object referenced by local variable will live until next ending `'}'` brace, which marks the end of its scope?

Comment: That is correct: it will live as long it's actively used by any managed code, but can disappear any time after that. Just being assigned to a variable doesn't count as 'used': that variable has to be mentioned lower down in the same method in order for the object in it to be kept alive.